# Function in R (Merge Bases)

Tags: r

I have the following bases in R.

```
table1<-data.frame(group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),price=c(10,20,30,10,20,30),
                                       visits=c(100,200,300,150,250,350))

table1<-table1 %>% arrange(price) %>% split(.$group)

$`1`
    group price visits
1     1    10    100
3     1    20    200
5     1    30    300

 $`2`
    group price visits
2     2    10    150
4     2    20    250
6     2    30    350

group_1<-data.frame(case_1=c(0.2,0.3,0.4),case_2=c(0.22,0.33,0.44))
group_2<-data.frame(case_1=c(0.3,0.4,0.5),case_2=c(0.33,0.44,0.55))
```

So, the question is How can I do the following operation without repeating it four times. I suppose that an apply function, or similar, will suit better.

```
sum(table1$`1`[,c("group")] * group_1[,c("case_1")])
sum(table1$`1`[,c("group")] * group_1[,c("case_2")])
sum(table2$`1`[,c("group")] * group_2[,c("case_1")])
sum(table2$`1`[,c("group")] * group_2[,c("case_2")])
```

Comment: There is no `table2`. I think you need `sum(table1$2[,c("group")] * group_2[,c("case_1")])` and `sum(table1$2[,c("group")] * group_2[,c("case_2")])` in last two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through step-by-step in the data you have provided and understanding what you are trying to do. Here is a suggestion using `mapply`.

```
group_list <- list(group_1, group_2)
mapply(function(x, y) colSums(x * y),split(table1$group, table1$group),group_list)

#          1    2
#case_1 0.90 2.40
#case_2 0.99 2.64
```

We take the groups in one list say `group_list`. Split `table1` by `group` and perform multiplication between them using `mapply` and take the column-wise sum. If I have understood you correctly, this is what you needed let me know if it is otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the initial dataset, we can do this using `group_by` operations

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(group_1, group_2) %>% 
         bind_cols(table1['group'], .) %>% 
         mutate(case_1 = group*case_1, case_2 = group*case_2) %>% 
         group_by(group) %>% 
         summarise_each(funs(sum))
# A tibble: 2 × 3 
#   group case_1 case_2
#    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1    0.9   0.99
#2     2    2.4   2.64
```

#### data

```
table1<-data.frame(group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),price=c(10,20,30,10,20,30),
                                   visits=c(100,200,300,150,250,350))
```